# mvc custom httpcookie used to authorize

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, httpcookie

Currently, I'm using the FOrmsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie to store an Id so I can use it on the next page that is "Authorized" (using custom authorizeattribute controller). But I'm currently thinking of making a custom cookie using httpcookie so I can store more data, or easily maintainable data. Was wondering if having the kind of cookie will I be able to authorize the current user to access the "Authorized" controllers? If so how do I go about it. 
Hope that made sense.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your extra stuff in a different cookie.  And if forms auth says the user isn't authenticated, don't read the other cookies.  No need to overload the purpose of the auth cookie (and non trivial to do so securely)

Comment: so what would be other benefits of creating a formsauthticket? if all i need would be in the formsauth already. just curious..

Answer (score 1):

There is a `UserData` property of the `FormsAuthenticationTicket`. It is a string so you will have to be able to serialize/deserialize any complex data.

Answer (score 1):

Good security design says dont store this information in a cookie - figure out another way (server side). Recently (octoberish) the ASP.Net POET vulnerability taught us that forms auth tickets could be forged because the machinekey could be determined and hence data encrypted as it would be on the server. I know - not exactly what you asked but I think it's important to not store sensitive data on the client side.